# Is it possible to use an OR with nested AND condition for filtering a table visual?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Hi Stack Overflow PowerBI/DAX Community,

I’m running into a problem which I fear it cannot easily or possibly be solved through PowerBI’s general visual/page filters or data transformation method since I’m using Direct Query mode for database connectivity. I’m hoping to perform table visual filtering using a multi-level filtering starting with an OR and a nested AND condition for two columns in a single table, see below sample dataset.

## IdentificationBadge Table Dataset

| ID Badge | ID | Title | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | Consultant I | Finance |
| 234 | 2 | Consultant I | IT |
| 345 | 3 | Consultant II | IT |
| NULL | 4 | Consultant II | IT |
| NULL | 5 | Consultant III | IT |
| 678 | 6 | Consultant III | IT |

## Desired Results

| ID Badge | ID | Title | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | 2 | Consultant I | IT |
| 345 | 3 | Consultant II | IT |
| NULL | 5 | Consultant III | IT |
| 678 | 6 | Consultant III | IT |

For the desired result:

- Page-level filtering is applied to the ‘Dept’ column displaying
  ‘IT’
- Visual-level (table) filter:

  - ‘Title’ column displaying ‘Consultants III’
  - OR
  - ‘Title’ column where the individual is not a ‘Consultant III’ AND ‘ID Badge’ column is not NULL

Basically, I’m looking for all staff in IT that’s either a Consultant III or you have an existing ID badge regardless of title. The visual-level filter with an OR statement that has a nested AND condition is the problem where I’m unsure if it can be applied at the filter pane-level. Unfortunately, the filter pane’s advanced filtering allows for OR conditions but only to values within the same column, not another column, so that won’t work. Basically, there isn’t a font-facing solution to apply multi-level filtering to the table visual.

Also, the reason I’m unsure whether using the filter pane can resolve my issue is using a DAX measure with IF(OR(conditions), 1, 0) then put that measure on the filter pane and set the flag to 1. I’ve seen some clever ways others are using this for a problem like mines, but not exactly and I may have interpreted it the wrong way. If this is possible, can someone shed some light on how this can be done?

I know this can be solved through data transformation where you can create another table/virtual table or add a custom column with DAX conditions, but like I mentioned, my data model is through direct query and not import mode, so I’m limited in how I can ETL through PowerBI’s PowerQuery. Although, I’m again unsure if this limitation prevents me from using DAX to apply my conditions against the direct query tables to return a column of data in a virtual table, which then I can use that column to filter in the filter pane. That would be the ideal solution.

So the question is: Is what I’m trying to achieve feasible though PowerBI’s tools or because I’m using Direct Query, it’ll have to be done from the db-level? If it can be done through BI tools, can you please share a sample solution? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a measure and then filter on that in your visual filter.
Example:

```
Consultant III or w/Badge = 
  SWITCH(TRUE(),
    SELECTEDVALUE('IdentificationBadge'[Title]) = "Consultant III", 1,
    NOT(ISBLANK(SELECTEDVALUE('IdentificationBadge'[ID Badge]))), 1
  )
```

In your visual filter, add this new measure and set it to `is not blank`

Based on your condition, wouldn't ID 3 & 4 (ConIII) appear in your desired results?

Here is a similar version but this one returns the count - you can use this one as well in your visual filter and if needed, for other visuals.

```
Consultant III or w/Badge count = 
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('IdentificationBadge'), (
      'IdentificationBadge'[Title] = "Consultant III"
    ) || (
      NOT( ISBLANK('IdentificationBadge'[ID Badge]) )
    )
  )
```

---

Kylifeofpy's modified DAX query from Sam as final solution:

```
Measure =
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    SELECTEDVALUE('IdentificationBadge'[Title]) = "Consultant III" ||
    (
        NOT(SELECTEDVALUE('IdentificationBadge'[Title]) = "Consultant III") &&
        NOT(ISBLANK(SELECTEDVALUE('IdentificationBadge'[ID Badge])))
    ),
    1,
    SELECTEDVALUE('IdentificationBadge'[Title]) = "Consultant III",
    2
)
```

Then apply the measure as a visual level filter and filter to 1

Comment: I tried the measure you suggested and nothing changed. Am I missing something? Also, I failed to mention that the first OR criteria is not only for a single title like "Consultant III" but multiple titles. Although, if this measure did work, can I simply continue to use the SELECTEDVALUE function then ('IdentificationBadge'[Title]) IN {"Consultant III", "different title1","different title2"}? Also to answer your question, ID 3 and 4 with title Consultant II will not appear since the first part of the OR statement filters to Consultant III title only, which filters all other titles OR ....

Comment: Yes, but your second part of the OR is (Not Consultant III and Badge ID in not null) which  both ID 3 and 4 match, just like ID 2 does. The measure above does work. And yes you can use IN `SELECTEDVALUE('IdentificationBadge'[Title]) IN { "T1", "T2" }`. Finally note that a `SWITCH` will stop on the first condition match.

Comment: You were right and that's a miscalculation on my part, so thank you for pointing that out. I've edited the post so it includes that data and added a minor variation. I also took your concept of the SWITCH(TRUE(), DAX and modified it to work for what I'm looking for and it works perfectly. I'll edit and add the final solution to your post. Thank you so very much for your assistance sir.